# Sympy. How to check input is numeric, sympy expression and if so if a symbol included in the expression?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I want to code some function that takes 1 input. The input could be numeric (integer, float, Sympy constant like `sympy.pi` or expression evaluated as real number like `sympy.sin(5)`), or could be a sympy expression (like `x**2-2*y+5`.

What I need is to determine:

1. Is the input is numeric (has no symbols)?
2. If the input is expression, does a specific variable exist?

I have tried `.free_symbols` and it fails if the input is integer and throws exception.
Also `str(input).isnumeric` fails if the input is `sympy.sin(5)`.

Comment: You probably will have to use several tests, since there are so many possibilities.  I'd explore `isinstance` to check for classes.  `isinstance(var, Basic)` seems to capture all the `sympy` options.  Or you may need a series of `try/except` blocks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a function in SymPy called `sympify` whose purpose is to turn non-SymPy objects into SymPy expressions e.g. an `int` becomes a SymPy `Integer` etc. If you sympify the input then you can use `free_symbols`:

```
In [6]: def inspect(expr):
   ...:     expr = sympify(expr)
   ...:     symbols = expr.free_symbols
   ...:     if not symbols:
   ...:         print(expr, 'has no symbols')
   ...:     else:
   ...:         print(expr, 'has these symbols:', ', '.join(map(str, symbols)))
   ...: 

In [7]: inspect(1)
1 has no symbols

In [8]: inspect(pi)
pi has no symbols

In [9]: inspect(x+y)
x + y has these symbols: y, x
```